# Language aesthetics

Tags: reference-request, theoretical-linguistics

This is my first post on this site.

My question is this: are there any theories developed (or simply thoughts put on paper) by language/linguistic theorists as to the aesthetical aspect of language?

What criteria must a language satisfy for it to be considered "rich"? Which phonemes don't go well together?

These are just a couple of silly examples of questions that I'd like to read someone's answers to.

Comment: Tolkien wrote a bit on that; the book *Inside Language* by Ross Smith explains his views.

Comment: It's a difficult question, because there is evidence that people's perception of aesthetics in language is strongly coloured by their social beliefs. See _Italian is Beuatiful, German is Ugly_ by Giles and Niedzielski, in _Language Myths_ by Bauer and Trudgill https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-3YokgYKoJMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=bauer+language+myths+beautiful&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSwv-syKHcAhUUglwKHeObBIcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=bauer%20language%20myths%20beautiful&f=false

Comment: As far as "richness" is concerned, there is likewise no reasonable standard to apply. _Rich_ with regard to language is a metaphor, indicating large resources; but all languages have large resources. Likewise, which sounds "don't go well together" is a matter of personal opinion (which in turn is often a matter of social opinion, like racism). Any scientific field avoids judgments that can't be attributed to anything beyond personal taste; as the Romans put it, _De gustibus non disputandum est_ 'Concerning tastes there are to be no disputes.'

Comment: Yes, sure. But I'm not aiming to adopt some golden rule here. I am merely interested in the (subjective) opinion of others. I mentioned that I'd like to read specialists' thoughts on the matter, precisely because specialists are more likely to be less influenced by their own preconceptions. I may add more context to my question later. (By the way, who on here thinks that Danish is beautiful?)

Comment: Alas, "primarily opinion-based" aren't allowed on Stack Exchange in general; Stack Exchange is not Quora. (That's not a value judgement; I actually prefer Quora.) In aesthetics, I don't think specialists are immune from preconceptions at all, precisely because they are extralinguistic. I still love the sound of German and the agglutinative structure of Turkish, and I know I'm a minority in that. :)

Comment: Yes (I am no stranger to SE). But more than anything else I am asking for references. Already Ross Smith's book is a delight.

Comment: While the question which language is aesthetically more pleasing than others is certainly opinion based, a question for scholarly references on language aesthetics isn't. I think the comments by boiko and Colin Fine can be expanded to valid answers.

Comment: @ColinFine: I think people's perception of aesthetics is absolutely influenced by social factors. But not exclusively, for example: when people dislike a language, they will mention some characteristics they find particularly cacophonious; many of those they may be repeating from others, but I think some first impressions will also be intrinsic. For example, it seems unlikely for anyone to find the presence of a feature that is also common in their own language ugly, regardless of social factors. More unusual features, on the other hand, might draw aesthetic judgements more easily. ...

Comment: What I'm particularly remembering, @Cerberus, is the experiment where English speakers were played recordings of a variety of (British) English accents, and asked to rate them aesthetically. As I recall it, British subjects largely rated urban accents (Brummie, Scouse, Glasgow, Cockney) the least attractive, while subjects from elsewhere in the Anglosphere rated RP and Cockney the most attractive, and showed no consistency among the rest.

Comment: Another example is sounds that they find difficult to pronounce: I suspect they're more likely to find those ugly, although of course there are always also social factors. // Moreover, those social factors could be explained in an answer. How and why, for example, do social factors influence the Dutch aversion of the Russian L sound (which I think many speakers of Dutch experience)? Then such *how*s and *why*s could be generalised into theories. And a short summary of such theories (e.g. from a monograph) would make for a great answer to this question! Sociolinguistics is super interesting.

Comment: @ColinFine: That's quite interesting! Some theories about that would make for a good answer. By the way, I suspect that social factors are most important when comparing between dialects well known to the observer, more so than when comparing foreign languages that the observer has never heard before.

Comment: Remarkably, I have actually found my copy of _Language Myths_ (most of my books are in boxes). The "Sources and further reading" at the end of the chapter mentions Chapter 2 of Howard Giles and Nikolaus Coupland _Language: Contexts and Consequences_, (Pacific Grove CA: Brooks/Cole 1992); and the chapter by Peter Trudgill and Howard Giles, 'Sociolinguistics and linguistic value judgements' in _Proceedings of a Colloquium on the Functionality of Language_ (Ghent: Studia Scientia, 1976)